# Row Level Access Control on Apache Cassandra

Tags: security, cassandra

What I am trying to achieve is similar to what DSE Cassandra provide here, but on Apache Cassandra: [Setting up Row Level Access Control (RLAC)](https://docs.datastax.com/eol/en/security/6.7/security/secRlac.html)

I've tried using [Materialized View](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/mvs.html) and grant SELECT permission on the created view to a specific role, but when I'm trying to access the view it returns an unauthorized error asking me to grant SELECT permission on the origin table.

Is there really no way to achieve this?

Comment: For anyone wondering, It is apparently not possible for now. I had to split data into different tables and set permissions table wise.